# Why is there such a difference in final accuracy between 700x700 px image and the same split up into 140x140 px in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have a relatively simple TF script for a convolutional neural network to classify microscopy images good or bad - manually this is done via the clarity of the image with bad images appearing blurry.

The full scans are obtained as 700x700 px images, so my initial thought was to simply input them into the network as is and see how it all comes out. For some reason, the validation accuracy doesn't seem to increase at all, just fluctuates around 80% whereas the accuracy on the training data clearly increases slowly up to close to 98%. Plot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZMEA.png .

This in itself isn't hugely odd, I just assumed my script was overfitting for some reason, so I was looking into other methods of reducing this.

Completely at random, I decided to split the 700x700 px images into 25 separate images of 140x140 px and try the exact same script on the new dataset, which appears much larger but in actual fact is (unless I'm missing something which is entirely possible) the same amount of data/information. Plot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyNJa.png .

Here, the training accuracy ends lower (probably just down to fewer epochs) but is much more consistent with the validation accuracy.

I'm confused as to why there is such a large difference in the training when I'm applying the same transformations to the same data, just split in a slightly different way? Please can somebody point me in the direction of an answer.

Here is my code in case it's useful (the only changes I make between different datasets are to do with the input shape of the images):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os
import random
from shutil import copyfile
import time

def create_train_val_dirs(root_path):
    """
    Creates directories for the train and test sets
    
    Args:
        root_path (string) - the base directory path to create subdirectories from
    
    Returns:
        None
    """ 

    os.makedirs(root_path)

    val_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'validation')
    train_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'training')
    os.makedirs(train_path)
    os.makedirs(val_path)

    os.makedirs(os.path.join(val_path, 'Good'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(val_path, 'Bad'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(train_path, 'Good'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(train_path, 'Bad'))

def split_data(SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, SPLIT_SIZE):

    """
    Splits the data into train and test sets
    
    Args:
        SOURCE_DIR (string): directory path containing the images
        TRAINING_DIR (string): directory path to be used for training
        VALIDATION_DIR (string): directory path to be used for validation
        SPLIT_SIZE (float): proportion of the dataset to be used for training
        
    Returns:
        None
    """
    

    im_list = random.sample(os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR), len(os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR)))

    for index, im in enumerate(im_list):
        if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im)) == 0:
            print(f"{im} is zero length, so ignoring.")
            continue
        if index <= SPLIT_SIZE*len(im_list):
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im), os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, im))
        else:
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im), os.path.join(VALIDATION_DIR, im))

def train_val_generators(TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size, input_size):
    """
    Creates the training and validation data generators
  
    Args:
        TRAINING_DIR (string): directory path containing the training images
        VALIDATION_DIR (string): directory path containing the testing/validation images
        batch_size (integer): Integer number of batches (amount of images trained per loop).
        input_size (tensor: (int, int)): Tensor containing the size of the input image, or 
        preferred input size (if different to the actual size it will be scaled). 
    
    Returns:
        train_generator, validation_generator - tuple containing the generators
    """

    # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class (don't forget to set the arguments to augment the images)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.0,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    vertical_flip=True
                                    )

    # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow_from_directory method
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=TRAINING_DIR,
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        target_size=target_size,
                                                        color_mode= 'grayscale')

    # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class (don't forget to set the rescale argument)
    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.0)

    # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow_from_directory method
    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                class_mode='binary',
                                                                target_size=target_size,
                                                                color_mode= 'grayscale')
    ### END CODE HERE
    return train_generator, validation_generator


# Find the start time
initial_t = time.perf_counter()

# Define paths
SSD_DIR = Path(os.getcwd())
DATA_DIR = SSD_DIR.joinpath(r'Python_scripts\Machine_Learning\Si111\Tensorflow\Dataset\Binary_notc\all\Splitting')
SOURCE_DIR = DATA_DIR.joinpath('Input_data')
ROOT_DIR = DATA_DIR.joinpath('ForRuns')

GOOD_SOURCE_DIR = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, "Good")
BAD_SOURCE_DIR = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR,"Bad")

TRAINING_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'training')
VALIDATION_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'validation')

TRAINING_GOOD_DIR = os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, "Good/")
VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR = os.path.join(VALIDATION_DIR, "Good/")

TRAINING_BAD_DIR = os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, "Bad/")
VALIDATION_BAD_DIR = os.path.join(VALIDATION_DIR, "Bad/")

try:
  create_train_val_dirs(ROOT_DIR)
  print(f'Creating directory at {ROOT_DIR}...')
except FileExistsError:
  print(f"{ROOT_DIR} already exists.")

# Empty directories in case you run this cell multiple times
if len(os.listdir(TRAINING_BAD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.scandir(TRAINING_BAD_DIR):
        os.remove(file.path)
if len(os.listdir(TRAINING_GOOD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.scandir(TRAINING_GOOD_DIR):
        os.remove(file.path)
if len(os.listdir(VALIDATION_BAD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.scandir(VALIDATION_BAD_DIR):
        os.remove(file.path)
if len(os.listdir(VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.scandir(VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR):
        os.remove(file.path)

# Define proportion of images used for training
split_size = .9

# Run the function
# NOTE: Messages about zero length images should be printed out
split_data(GOOD_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_GOOD_DIR, VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR, split_size)
split_data(BAD_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_BAD_DIR, VALIDATION_BAD_DIR, split_size)

batch_size = 32
target_size = (140, 140)
epochs = 25
layers = 2
starting = 512

train_generator, validation_generator = train_val_generators(TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size=batch_size, input_size=target_size)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ 
      
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape= (140,140,1)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
  ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Begin training!
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)


# Save the model, history and accuracy plot
save_name = f'{epochs}epochs_{layers}layers_{starting}Starting'
Models_dir = SSD_DIR.joinpath('ML/Models/TensorFlow/Si(111)')

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epoch_range = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epoch_range, acc, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epoch_range, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.savefig(os.path.join(Models_dir, f'acc_plots/{save_name}.png'))
model.save(os.path.join(Models_dir, f'models/{save_name}.h5'))


# convert the history.history dict to a pandas DataFrame:     
hist_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history) 

# or save to csv: 
hist_csv_file = os.path.join(Models_dir, f'histories/{save_name}.csv')
with open(hist_csv_file, mode='w') as f:
    hist_df.to_csv(f)

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
plt.close()
```

I've tried searching for instances of people using larger image datasets (by larger I mean 200px+ as most basic TensorFlow ML tutorials use very small images) but I can't seem to find anything similar.

Thanks in advance for any help.